# Getting an error when I make a switch with a string

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

I am getting an error message when I try to make a switch with a String. Here is the error:

```
incompatible types found: 
java.lang.String 
required: int 
switch(monthName){
```

This makes it seem like I can only make a switch with an int but I was pretty sure that in the more recent Java versions you can make a switch with a String. Here's the code that is giving me the error:

```
switch(monthName){
        case "December"://Always has 31 days
            daysLeft = 31;
            daysLeft -= dayOfMonth;
            break;
        case "November"://Always has 30 days
            daysLeft = 61;
            daysLeft -= dayOfMonth;
            break;
        case "October"://Always has 31 days
            daysLeft = 92;
            daysLeft -= dayOfMonth;
            break;
        case "September"://Always has 30 days
            daysLeft = 122;
            daysLeft -= dayOfMonth;
            break;
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Switch on strings is available since Java 7.

Comment: This was the problem. I updated java and restarted and now it compiles correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum constants are permitted**

Answer (score 0):

Define enum in your class:

```
public enum MonthName {
    December, November, October, September
}
```

Use val variable to provide switch functionality on basis of string input-

```
String val = "December";//can be taken from user through Scanner class
MonthName monthName = MonthName.valueOf(val);//Enum class object

switch (monthName) {
    case December://Always has 31 days
        daysLeft = 31;
        daysLeft -= dayOfMonth;
        break;
    case November://Always has 30 days
        daysLeft = 61;
        daysLeft -= dayOfMonth;
        break;
    case October://Always has 31 days
        daysLeft = 92;
        daysLeft -= dayOfMonth;
        break;
    case September://Always has 30 days
        daysLeft = 122;
        daysLeft -= dayOfMonth;
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(dayOfMonth + "---" + daysLeft);//Test of output
}
```

Comment: Hello. I edited your answer a little to change "Code snippet" tool to "Code sample". Use "Code snippet" to present HTML/CSS/JS examples (code which can actually be run via browser). To format code like Java use "Code sample" (marked with `{}` in editor).